# Program that "fences" installed programs so they do not contaminate Windows?

Tags: windows, sandbox

A while ago, I saw a program that basically created a sort of "sandbox" for a program before it was installed. The main benefit of using this programs to install other programs was that it allowed for the complete removal of that program after it was installed. I think it may have also basically sandboxed the program being installed, but I am not sure about that. I can't remember what the name of this program was. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many sandboxing programs, here are some of them:

[Sandboxie](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sandboxing%20software&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandboxie.com%2F&ei=j6DWTsPYO-Lo0QH6r_2RAg&usg=AFQjCNE0DZjkATr731tATTbC-pT15myyRA), [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/for-home) and [BufferZone Pro](http://www.trustware.com/BufferZone-Pro/) (it is free).
Note that sandboxing and installing really do not go together. Sandboxing means allow no changes to presist, and that is the whole purpose of installing. Avira sends warnings when it thinks the program is doing something fishy, but the others just do not not allow changes to presist.

If you are so worried about viruses, it may be worthwhile to use a VM as the "ultimate sandbox" and wipe it if you think there are viruses.

Comment: Actually, "sandboxing" and "installing" go hand in hand very well, it's what [Application Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization) is all about.

Comment: Depending on how far you want to take it, a virtual machine may be exactly what you want.  VmWare Player is free as long as you have another license for your os of choice.

Comment: @afrazier : Sandboxing can also be used in the sense of making an application portable. So no, installing does not go hand in hand with it.

Comment: @surfasb: It depends on what you mean by "hand in hand". I only meant that they go together very well, but one doesn't necessarily mean the other.

Comment: @afrazier: Very true.  I misread.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)? It's the only program I've used that does what you describe, although I'm sure there are others.